# emacs -nw -q takes long time

Tags: start-up

`emacs -nw -q` or `emacs -nw -Q` takes more than 10 seconds to start in terminal, but the result of `M-x emacs-init-time` is 0.0 seconds, and the `emacs` takes shorter time (still more than 5s) than `emacs -nw -q` or `emacs -nw -Q` and the result `M-x emacs-init-time` is 3.5 seconds, this is really weird.

Does anyone know what is going on?

FYI:

CentOS 6.5 32-bit

GNU Emacs 24.4.2 (compiled from the source code at the official gnu website)

Comment: I take it the regular `emacs` from the CentOS repos does not have this problem? What flags did you build with?

Comment: Default `./configure ; make ; sudo make install`

Comment: Does the regular `emacs` as packaged for CentOS exhibit the same problem?

Comment: @rekado Actually the compiled Emacs is not like this slow in the beginning, than I installed some libraries because of company's needs and configured my KDE environment a bit, after I restarted my computer, it became slow, but I don't think that will affect Emacs, I didn't installed the Emacs from the ISO file since it is v32.1, so I cannot get the result, but I think it is normal. And the configuration is directly copied from my personal Fedora 21 environment because my working computer cannot get the access to the internet, so the el files are not re-compiled, I'll re-compile them tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

One slow startup problem is usually that you don't have your machines fully qualified hostname declared in /etc/hosts which causes emacs to hang at some syscall during startup. However, that would not explain why `emacs` is faster than `emacs -Q`.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it by adding machine name (not fully qualified) to /etc/hosts as a synonym for localhost. strace revealed that it used before 5 seconds opening an IP connection and another 4+4 seconds in two ioctls and still some seconds in other handling of these connections. Now it starts immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try running it under `strace`:

`strace -o /tmp/yow emacs -Q -nw`

then look at `/tmp/yow` and you should get an idea of where it's hanging.